Ansible: append to config line when entry is not present
I am trying to automate a config entry modification. I have AIX servers which have a file login.cfg and there is a line on which available shells are configured. It is like this:
usw:
        shells = /bin/sh,/bin/bsh,/bin/csh,/bin/ksh,/bin/tsh,/bin/ksh93,/usr/bin/sh,/usr/bin/bsh,/usr/bin/csh,/usr/bin/ksh,/usr/bin/tsh,/usr/bin/ksh93,/usr/bin/rksh,/usr/bin/rksh93,/usr/sbin/uucp/uucico,/usr/sbin/snappd,/usr/sbin/sliplogin

        maxlogins = 32767
        logintimeout = 60

My goal is to append ,/usr/bin/bash to the end of the shells line, when it is not already present. The order of shells is not uniform among the hosts, for a reason.
My attempt to achieve this modification is like this snippet below - for testing purposes I just edit login.cfg locally. It has two steps: first testing if bash is already present and then edit the line if not.
---
- name: test adding /bin/bash to the end of the line IF NOT THERE
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Check if bash is already there
    shell: "grep -E 'shells = .*/usr/bin/bash' {{ playbook_dir }}/login.cfg"
    ignore_errors: yes
    register: result
  - name: add entry if not there
    lineinfile:
      backrefs: yes
      line: '\g<list>,/usr/bin/bash'
      path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/login.cfg"
      regexp: "(?P<list> +shells =.*)"
    when: result.rc != 0

My question is if there is a method to avoid the testing using shell: module. Is there any more Ansible-ish way to do the same?

Since the data structure of  your login.cfg looks like an INI you can the generic approach show under "How to append an option?"

Reading the reference about login.cfg File it seems the mentioned approach might need some enhancements to address your case fully. Going to see what's possible what's possible here ...

Let's parse the content of the file first. For example, if you replace the equal signs with colons you get YAML
  _regex: '\s*='
  _replace: ':'
  login_dict: "{{ lookup('file', 'login.cfg') |
                  regex_replace(_regex, _replace) |
                  from_yaml }}"

gives
  login_dict:
    usw:
      logintimeout: 60
      maxlogins: 32767
      shells: /bin/sh,/bin/bsh,/bin/csh,/bin/ksh,/bin/tsh,/bin/ksh93,/usr/bin/sh,/usr/bin/bsh,/usr/bin/csh,/usr/bin/ksh,/usr/bin/tsh,/usr/bin/ksh93,/usr/bin/rksh,/usr/bin/rksh93,/usr/sbin/uucp/uucico,/usr/sbin/snappd,/usr/sbin/sliplogin

Split the shells
 shells: "{{ login_dict.usw.shells | split(',') }}"

gives
  shells:
  - /bin/sh
  - /bin/bsh
  - /bin/csh
  - /bin/ksh
  - /bin/tsh
  - /bin/ksh93
  - /usr/bin/sh
  - /usr/bin/bsh
  - /usr/bin/csh
  - /usr/bin/ksh
  - /usr/bin/tsh
  - /usr/bin/ksh93
  - /usr/bin/rksh
  - /usr/bin/rksh93
  - /usr/sbin/uucp/uucico
  - /usr/sbin/snappd
  - /usr/sbin/sliplogin

and, as required, "append /usr/bin/bash to the end of the shells line, when it is not already present"
  shells_append: /usr/bin/bash
  shells_update: "{{ (shells_append in shells) |
                     ternary(shells, shells + [shells_append]) |
                     join(',') }}"

Use shells_update in the module lineinfile
    - name: add entry if not there
      lineinfile:
        backrefs: true
        path: login.cfg
        regexp: '^(\s*shells)\s*=.*$'
        line: '\1 = {{ shells_update }}'

Optionally, you can update the dictionary
  usw_update:
    usw:
      shells: "{{ shells_update }}"
  login_update: "{{ login_dict | combine(usw_update, recursive='true') }}"

gives
  login_update:
    usw:
      logintimeout: 60
      maxlogins: 32767
      shells: /bin/sh,/bin/bsh,/bin/csh,/bin/ksh,/bin/tsh,/bin/ksh93,/usr/bin/sh,/usr/bin/bsh,/usr/bin/csh,/usr/bin/ksh,/usr/bin/tsh,/usr/bin/ksh93,/usr/bin/rksh,/usr/bin/rksh93,/usr/sbin/uucp/uucico,/usr/sbin/snappd,/usr/sbin/sliplogin,/usr/bin/bash

and create a template
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for section,conf in login_update.items() %}
          {{ section }}:
          {% for k,v in conf.items() %}
                  {{ k }} = {{ v }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}

gives
  msg: |-
    usw:
            shells = /bin/sh,/bin/bsh,/bin/csh,/bin/ksh,/bin/tsh,/bin/ksh93,/usr/bin/sh,/usr/bin/bsh,/usr/bin/csh,/usr/bin/ksh,/usr/bin/tsh,/usr/bin/ksh93,/usr/bin/rksh,/usr/bin/rksh93,/usr/sbin/uucp/uucico,/usr/sbin/snappd,/usr/sbin/sliplogin,/usr/bin/bash
            maxlogins = 32767
            logintimeout = 60

Copy the content to the file
    - name: copy content
      copy:
        dest: login.cfg
        content: |
          {% for section,conf in login_update.items() %}
          {{ section }}:
          {% for k,v in conf.items() %}
                  {{ k }} = {{ v }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}

Both tasks are idempotent and give the same result. There might be a systemic option on how to parse this format in AIX.


Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    _regex: '\s*='
    _replace: ':'
    login_dict: "{{ lookup('file', 'login.cfg') |
                    regex_replace(_regex, _replace) |
                    from_yaml }}"

    shells: "{{ login_dict.usw.shells | split(',') }}"
    shells_append: /usr/bin/bash
    shells_update: "{{ (shells_append in shells) |
                       ternary(shells, shells + [shells_append]) |
                       join(',') }}"

    usw_update:
      usw:
        shells: "{{ shells_update }}"
    login_update: "{{ login_dict | combine(usw_update, recursive='true') }}"
    

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: login_dict

    - debug:
        var: shells

    - debug:
        var: shells_update

    - name: add entry if not there
      lineinfile:
        backrefs: true
        path: login.cfg
        regexp: '^(\s*shells)\s*=.*$'
        line: '\1 = {{ shells_update }}'
      when: lineinfile | d(false) | bool


    - debug:
        var: usw_update

    - debug:
        var: login_update

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for section,conf in login_update.items() %}
          {{ section }}:
          {% for k,v in conf.items() %}
                  {{ k }} = {{ v }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}

    - name: copy content
      copy:
        dest: login.cfg
        content: |
          {% for section,conf in login_update.items() %}
          {{ section }}:
          {% for k,v in conf.items() %}
                  {{ k }} = {{ v }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
      when: content | d(false) | bool


The optimized play below will skip the task if the shell is in the list
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    _regex: '\s*='
    _replace: ':'
    login_dict: "{{ lookup('file', 'login.cfg') |
                    regex_replace(_regex, _replace) |
                    from_yaml }}"

    shells: "{{ login_dict.usw.shells | split(',') }}"
    shells_append: /usr/bin/bash
    

  tasks:

    - name: add entry if not there
      lineinfile:
        backrefs: true
        path: login.cfg
        regexp: '^(\s*shells)\s*=.*$'
        line: '\1 = {{ (shells + [shells_append]) | join(",") }}'
      when: shells_append not in shells


This can be further simplified
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    _regex: '\s*='
    _replace: ':'
    login_conf: "{{ lookup('file', 'login.cfg') |
                    regex_replace(_regex, _replace) |
                    from_yaml }}"
    shells: "{{ login_conf.usw.shells }}"
    shells_append: /usr/bin/bash
    

  tasks:

    - name: add entry if not there
      lineinfile:
        backrefs: true
        path: login.cfg
        regexp: '^(\s*shells)\s*=.*$'
        line: '\1 = {{ [shells, shells_append] | join(",") }}'
      when: shells_append not in shells



Wow, that is a lot stuff to learn from. There are things that will be really useful for me for another task. But eventually I found a solution which is waaay simpler.
The main reason of my struggles was that I thought  quotation marks and apostrophes are interchangeable. In reality they are not, especially for regex
"...rexeg expression" - will be incorrect
'...regex expression' - will be correct

One quick and cheap way to do it could be the following:
First, it would be necessary to gather facts about the Remote Nodes. Even if it is not the best way it could simply be done via a minimal example
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    FACT: "shells"
    SEARCH_STRING: "/usr/bin/bash"
    SEARCH_FILE: "login.cfg"

  tasks:

  # grep string from Remote File

  - name: Gathering Custom Facts
    shell:
      cmd: "grep {{ FACT }} {{ SEARCH_FILE }} | tr -d ' ' | cut -d '=' -f 2"
    register: shells
    # Since this is a reporting, gathering facts task
    # it needs to deliver a result in any case
    failed_when: shells.rc != 0 and shells.rc != 1
    check_mode: false
    changed_when: false

  - name: Show available remote shells
    debug:
      msg: "{{ shells.stdout }}"
    when: ansible_check_mode

resulting into an output of
TASK [Show available remote shells] *********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg: /bin/sh,/bin/bsh,/bin/csh,/bin/ksh,/bin/tsh,/bin/ksh93,/usr/bin/sh,/usr/bin/bsh,/usr/bin/csh,/usr/bin/ksh,/usr/bin/tsh,/usr/bin/ksh93,/usr/bin/rksh,/usr/bin/rksh93,/usr/sbin/uucp/uucico,/usr/sbin/snappd,/usr/sbin/sliplogin

Q: "Is there a method to avoid the testing using the shell module?"
A better approach is shown under How to search for a string in a Remote File using Ansible?, Ansible: How to append an option? or just use Custom facts directly.
Second, append entry if it is not contained already
  - name: Append entry if it is not contained already
    lineinfile:
      path: "{{ SEARCH_FILE }}"
      regexp: ".*{{ FACT }} =.*"
      line: "        {{ FACT }} = {{ shells.stdout }},{{ SEARCH_STRING }}"
    when: not shells.stdout is search(SEARCH_STRING)


My main question was how to find out if an entry is present in a config file, without using shell: module. My answer is to use lineinfile: with check_mode: yes
By the way, up to this moment I was thinking that quotation marks and apostrophes are interchangeable in Ansible playbooks. The experience shows that they are not. The line: row, which contains regex bacrefs, gave me syntax error with quotation marks, but is working fine with apostrophes
---
- name: testing the behavior of check_mode option
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    searchstr: "/usr/bin/bash"
    logincfgfile: "{{ playbook_dir }}/login.cfg"
  become: no
  tasks:
  - name: check if line is present
    lineinfile:
      path: "{{ logincfgfile }}"
      regex: "shells = .*{{ searchstr }}.*"
      state: absent
    check_mode: yes
    register: entrypresent
  - name: add shell entry if it was not present
    lineinfile:
      backrefs: yes
      path: "{{ logincfgfile }}"
      regex: "(?P<shellsline> *shells = .*)"
      line: '\g<shellsline>,{{ searchstr }}'
      # line: "\g<shellsline>,{{ searchstr }}"    # not working with quotation marks
    when: entrypresent.found == 0

For the sake of simplicity I am using a local file to experiment on. This is defined in logincfgfile. I am trying do delete the line with the shell definitions, including the shell to be added, but I do it in check_mode, so there is no real change to the file, just collecting data - and registering into entrypresent variable. The output of lineinfile has a field, called found, which holds the number of matches. If it is zero, thus no matches, the next task adds the new shell entry.
